# ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘vector’ with no type

Tags: c++, g++

when i compile my project i'm getting that weird errors for tools.h/tools.h.
The string and vector classes are used via std namespace. I just can't see any mistakes.

```
g++ powerpi.cpp structs.cpp xmlreader.cpp tools.cpp -o powerpi
In file included from structs.cpp:5:
tools.h:5: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘vector’ with no type
tools.h:5: error: invalid use of ‘::’
tools.h:5: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘<’ token
```

tools.h

```
class Tools {
  public:
    template<typename T>
    static std::string convert(T);
    static std::vector<std::string> explode(std::string, std::string);
};
```

tools.cpp

```
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

#include "tools.h"

template <typename T>
std::string Tools::convert(T Number)
{ 
  std::ostringstream ss;
  ss << Number;
  return ss.str();
}

std::vector<std::string> Tools::explode(std::string delimiter, std::string str)
{   
    std::vector<std::string> arr;

    int strleng = str.length();
    int delleng = delimiter.length();
    if (delleng==0)
        return arr;//no change

    int i=0;
    int k=0;
    while( i<strleng )
    {   
        int j=0;
        while (i+j<strleng && j<delleng && str[i+j]==delimiter[j])
            j++;
        if (j==delleng)//found delimiter
        {
            arr.push_back(  str.substr(k, i-k) );
            i+=delleng;
            k=i;
        }
        else
        {
            i++;
        }
    }
    arr.push_back(  str.substr(k, i-k) );
    return arr;
}
```

I can't see any mistakes. How about you?

Comment: Missing `#include`. (And probably for `<string>` as well, though you seem to have been unlucky on that and not gotten an error)

Comment: You should never assume something else will include headers for you.

Comment: The error message is about structs.cpp but you posted tools.cpp...

Comment: @MarcGlisse Nope the header is included in structs.cpp, but the actual error is in tools.h

Comment: Since `convert` is a template, you should have its definition in the header.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your file "struct.cpp", you need to `#include <string>` as well as `#include <vector>`.

Of course, since everything that uses "tools.h" needs these, you may want to stick them at the top in "tools.h" instead, so that you can include "tools.h" anywhere it is needed.

Comment: Thank you, that worked.
Now i getting these erros:
`/tmp/ccDocdbk.o: In function `Gpio::toString()':
structs.cpp:(.text+0x190): undefined reference to `std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > Tools::convert<int>(int)'`

gpio.cpp
`std::string Gpio::toString() {
  std::string str = std::string("Gpio { name: ") + name + std::string("; gpio: ") + Tools::convert(gpio) + std::string(" }");
  return str;
}`

Comment: @toni thats another issue, namely the definition of templates in the .cpp. Google and/or search SO for "template undefined reference" - You'll get references to that problem a million times and the correct answer three million times ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Add to your header:

```
#include <vector>
```