# ISO C++ forbids declaration of 'vector' with no type

Tags: c++, arduino

I am having an issue with arduino c and the StandardCplusplus package. I am trying to declare a vector but get the following error:

> Node.h:26: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of 'vector' with no type
>
> Node.h:26: error: invalid use of '::'
>
> Node.h:26: error: expected ';'before '<' token

Looking at other questions, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17472035/iso-c-forbids-declaration-of-vector-with-no-type) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1552170/help-with-error-iso-c-forbids-declaration-of-vector-with-no-type) people forget the include or use std, but I have done both.

```
/*
 Node.h
*/
#ifndef Node_h
#define Node_h
#include "Arduino.h"
#include <StandardCplusplus.h>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iterator>
class Node
{
  public:
    Node(int size);
    ~Node();
    float bias();
    void set_bias(float);
    void print();
    void fprint(FILE *);
    float compute(std::vector<float> inputs);
    void setWeights(std::vector<float> inws);
    void set_weight(int,float);
    float dutyCycle();
    
  protected:
    std::vector<float> _weights;               //input weights:30
    float level;
    void init(int size);
    std::vector<int> firelog;
    
};

#endif
```

thanks

edit: I am using the arduino 1.5.5 ide compiler.

edit2: I have removed everything except the vector as per comments yielding:

```
/*
 Node.h
*/
#ifndef Node_h
#define Node_h

#include <vector>
class Node
{
  public:
      Node();
      ~Node();
      std::vector<int> test;
};

#endif
```

which still outputs the error:

> In file included from Node.cpp:1:
>
> Node.h:13: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of 'vector' with no type
>
> Node.h:13: error: invalid use of '::'
>
> Node.h:13: error: expected ';' before '<' token

Comment: What's with the inconsistent naming conventions? `set_weight` and `setWeights`...

Comment: names begining with underscores are reserved, if memory serves. But that's probably not it.

Comment: It seems to work fine at this [ideone example](http://ideone.com/3t9WWi). Is there anything we aren't seeing here?

Comment: What does this header #include <StandardCplusplus.h> do here?!

Comment: Have you tried inspecting the vector include to make sure that it actually exists, and isn't like, a blank file, or corrupted in some way?

Comment: Unless the headers `"Arduino.h"` or `<StandardCplusplus.h>` do something weird this looks as if it should compile. I would preprocess the file (using the ubiquitous `-E` option) and see what the offending lines turned into.

Comment: The error is in an included header and the error messages is stripped: -1

Comment: What's with the extraneous/gratuitous `#include` directives? Your header does not use functionality from `"Arduino.h"`, `<StandardCplusplus.h>` (whatever that is), `<string>`, or `<iterator>`, so why are you #including those files in this header file? If you program like this elsewhere, it's very hard to find the cause of your error. **Get rid of those gratuitous `#include` directives.**

Comment: @DavidHammen I have removed all of the other #includes, and the same error persists. see above edits.

Comment: @DieterLücking I am providing all of the output the Arduino IDE is giving, nothing has been stripped.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just ran into this same issue and was able to resolve it by including StandardCplusplus.h in my main sketch .ino file, rather than in the C++ class header file that I wanted to use the vector in. So, it looks roughly like this:

```
/*
 Main.ino (or whatever your main sketch file is called)
*/

#include <StandardCplusplus.h>
#include "Node.h"

// ...

void setup()
{
}

void loop()
{
}
```

Then in Node.h:

```
/*
 Node.h
*/
#ifndef Node_h
#define Node_h

#include <vector>
class Node
{
  public:
      Node();
      ~Node();
      std::vector<int> test;
};

#endif
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you read the documentation? From http://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/FAQ.html#faq_cplusplus ,

> **Can I use C++ on the AVR?**
>
> Basically yes, C++ is supported (assuming your compiler has been configured and compiled to support it, of course). Source files ending in .cc, .cpp or .C will automatically cause the compiler frontend to invoke the C++ compiler. Alternatively, the C++ compiler could be explicitly called by the name avr-c++.
>
> However, there's currently no support for libstdc++, the standard support library needed for a complete C++ implementation. This imposes a number of restrictions on the C++ programs that can be compiled.

Comment: What I read here is that you can use C++ on the Arduino but none of the things that make the language powerful.

Comment: Right, which is why I was trying to use [StandardCplusplus](https://github.com/maniacbug/StandardCplusplus/blob/master/README.md), which is a package that allows the std on arduino.

Answer (score 0):

Preprocess the file using the `-E` option of the compiler and removing stuff the compiler will complain about like `-c` and `-o`. Since you don't show how you try to compile the code it is impossible to advise how the invocation should look exactly. Note, that the output is bound to be large, i.e., you should redirect it either to a file or pipe it to something like `less`.

Once the file is processed, check that the declarations in the `Node` class still read something like the original (what exactly the result will look like depends on the compiler). In particular verify that the `std` isn't magically gone (

If the line looks OK check that the `<vector>` header got properly included. You should be able to fine a line match `#.*vector` which, e.g., looks like this in the preprocessed output on my machine:

```
# 1 "/opt/gcc-current/include/c++/4.9.0/vector" 1 3
```

After that line you'd expect actual declaration of the `std::vector` template (well, at some point; it may include other headers first). If the compiler find a different file which happens to be called `vector` the declarations of `std::vector` may have gone missing.

Another candidate may be something defining the include guard for the `<vector>` header. That would be before the code of the `vector` file whose location was found above. For example, the file `/opt/gcc-current/include/c++/4.9.0/vector` uses `_GLIBCXX_VECTOR` as include guard which is unlikely to be defined but I don't know what your headers are doing.